# AWS RDS Error Code: 2013 Lost Connection to MySQL server during Query

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, connection, amazon-rds

Been having the problem with the simple query that requires more than 60 seconds to be completed.

- AWS RDS DB Parameters are set into values of 9999 for net_read_timeout, connect_timeout, interactive_timeout, net_read_timeout, net_write_timeout, wait_timeout, max_allowed_packet.
- AWS RDS has been reboot too after the changes.
- The client workbench we use to remote access the AWS RDS I have set the same values for the above parameters.
- The client workbench preferences we have set MySQLSession DBMS to 9999 too.

Anyone have this issue too?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I haven't found a solution so far. I'm trying to do a LOAD DATA INFILE.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, max_allowed_packet is the reason for this. sometimes on Server side max packet and sometimes from the client side. Try to make this change,

In the RDS Parameter group set `max_allowed_packet to 1G` and in the mysql client while connecting use `--max-allowed-packet=1G`.

Comment: This solution did not fix my problem.

Comment: Hey @philippe  check write related parameters, most of the time you need to set max allowed packets values under [MySQL] client side parameters. For write based parameters, check net write timeout parameter.

Comment: Thanks @bhuvanesh, I did check and modify the parametres, now the command takes forever (more than 15 mins), the data file is pretty small (400KB)

Comment: Then its time to jump to transaction level process. Check the innodb_trx and locks tables. You will get the exact cause for this.